# Using Ionic Appflow Build for non Ionic framework project

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic-appflow

Is there a way to use Ionic Appflow to build and non-Ionic Framework project just using Capacitor?

Cause a on a blog by Ionic it said:

> Appflow is the official Mobile DevOps platform built
> by the Ionic team, focused on bringing powerful Mobile DevOps
> workflows to hybrid app developers across Capacitor and Cordova
> whether or not they are using Ionic Framework.

[Link to the blog](https://ionicframework.com/blog/appflow-not-just-another-ci-cd-service/)

Answer (score 0):

Ionic Framework (the UI library) is not required.

However, as of today, Appflow requires an Ionic config file and a package.json file. See that link for details (ignore the rest of that guide). If you're building a modern web app, you'll likely have a package json already. for the ionic config, just create it manually but for "integrations" swap in "capacitor".

You'll also use the Ionic CLI for some of the configuration (like "ionic deploy" as you shared).